# See installed extensions on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

Looking for a way to see which extensions an iOS 8 device has on it.

I know its possible to see whether there are specific apps on a device, so I am guessing it would be something similar.

Thanks for any help!

This is what I mean by seeing if specific apps are on a device, though it could still be installed if the url scheme isn't available

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]) {
// Facebook app is installed
}
```

so my main question is if there is something similar, but for extensions

Comment: Why do you say it's possible to see whether specific apps are on a device? It's possible to see whether handlers for specific URL schemes are installed but apps may not expose URL schemes and many apps may expose the same scheme. I'm not aware of any other mechanism but maybe I'm out of date?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that — I feel like I tagged on a question for my benefit to yours.

Comment: If the app is present on an iOS 8 device, it is likely that the extension is present also.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Extensions don't register URL handlers.